# Enforce Types of one Field to contain only keys that are in array of other field

Tags: typescript, generics, conditional-types

How can I enforce the keys of an object to be only valid if they actually are contained in an array of a union type?

```
type Category = 'software' | 'hardware' | 'books'

type Item = {
    categories: Category[];
    registry: Partial<{[key in Category]: string}>
}


//Should be invalid because 'books' is not in categories array:
const myInValidItem: Item = {
    categories: ['software', 'hardware'],
    registry: { books: 'blabla' }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=30&ssc=3&pln=8&pc=1#)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution probably is to define a helper function that checks related `registry` and  `categories` types:

```
function createParts<T extends Category[]>(
  categories: T, registry: { [K in T[number]]?: string }
) {
  return { categories, registry };
}

const myInValidItem: Item = createParts(
  ["software", "hardware"],
  { books: "blabla" }
) // error, books not contained
```

You can also create a more restrictive `Item` type and use it for the function parameter:

```
const myInValidItem = {
    categories: ['software', 'hardware'],
    registry: { books: 'blabla' }
} as const // const assertion here to preserve the tuple type

type ConstrainedItem<T extends readonly Category[]> = {
    categories: T;
    registry: Partial<{ [key in T[number]]: string }>
}

declare function doSomething<T extends readonly Category[]>(item: ConstrainedItem<T>): void

doSomething(myInValidItem) // error
doSomething(myValidItem)
```

[Playground 1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=11&pln=8&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghsCBzA9gJxFAvFARAZxQDNgB3ONCXKAHzwAsKATcy6u3AIxRQGt9cAbgBQw0JCgBJRAFtsUAN7CoUAMYJk6AJYR8ALlgbUGANoBdESspIt%20YBgMAFCsC1wANgB4FUE7wiYWgB2hojGIGYGdmjBSFAAvgB8IvEiwqooQXZQMiCSQQBqHlpM0hAyBmVyOKqUGs5owPgAFMq%20BMRkFFQANAzMrFRmPW0%203Hz6eJzucNNw1PHCAJRQAPSrUBBoaOh94-xQQSjAapnAcMEQTKLpmdm5Re4lVZWy8rUQ9S4tbSYdJINcH1cIw0CxurhhqMoIQAd0DFwZnMFss1htSOh%20DciABXIKqVyZNR1RANJqeAAqmwAHoggkx8KFNKYzIlWip1GFtLoDBS%20tZbPYQAYfCYANJQYJQCkmII4mScLZmMwAfii9liCVRSisEGAOLQIR8nOZOnw-OQgowCRSwiAA), [Playground 2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=11&pln=14&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghsCBzA9gJxFAvFA5AZxQDNgB3ONCXKAHzwAsKATcy6u3AIxRQGt9cAKEGhIUAJKIAttigBvQVCVQAxgmToAlhHwAuWOtQYA2gF0A3IuWUkm-MAz6AChWCa4AGwA8cqMd4QmJoAdgaIRiCm%20vZoIUhQAL4AfIIJwqLQMCjBMXAhEEySEFJeACpQEAAeiMFM%20FCUcEzZHpjw4eggZkmyCsqqhlo6%20qWW-TZ2DiDOru7evv6BUCFQpcbBAK5SnBBoplFQMXGJKWmCAPTnAMr0KBseTFA7y8EAbp6ajztqG-jQXDx%20NQ7FBgihgC8Bh1YjooBQ0HBpoIVNl7FApCBxMEAGofQrSXpWJRqaHaPR%20AjEMgUKgAGgYzFYVFMtKJDWQk0c8iegPJXA8cE4AuoaQScPqKJywGEkrRGNxHk%20RRkOD6yhJGhh5OMlJITNw9NwjDQLBpuBZbImMWm3MIepp%20n5guFiVS4tUqOlgiYEBUAsoUCIG2CKjc2SgzSuKCkEGA9DiZQq1QgtXqjWawVaYU1XVMSQAFJppPoslKEfl8cUykkAJT6V4oT7CSPR2Px4JIfMYrEKpXSGvelBRmNxuJdkC9ytSGtAA)

Answer (score 0):

The same solution that ford04 has suggested, but in a slightly different interpretation:

```js
type Category = 'software' | 'hardware' | 'books';

const createItem = <T extends Category>(item: {
  categories: T[];
  registry: { [key in T]?: string }
}) => item;

//Should be invalid because 'books' is not in categories array:
const myInValidItem = createItem({
  categories: ['software', 'hardware'],
  registry: { 'books': 'blabla' }
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghsCBzA9gJxFAvFA5AZxQDNgB3ONCXKAHzwAsKATcy6u3AIxRQGt9cAbgBQwgMYoAdvmBQxlBBACSiALbYoAHgAqUCAA9EkpvliLUGAHwAKAJZqAXFADewqHPPpbEfE%200BtAF0Rd0okWxkMJ2cof14ITFtJKG1AgH4nSKSkKABfYVyASmxLKHsIVRFhAHpqgGV6FABXABsmKE5oJIA3OBbbds6xOCb8aC4efmoIqEkUWSSPRAtvUwo0OBAHcSkZKFUQJUkANT6BlQqNeQhFC9VrV3dh5a8fJ38CYjIKKgAaBmYrCogV%20bigYQiwCiLjw3D4AicXBacE4yOo%20SKIiAA)